# Как узнать имя или индекс из списка CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как узнать имя или индекс из списка `CheckedListBox` когда я кликаю по одному из элементов списка?

И можно ли узнать информацию о том элементе по которому кликаю не только в `CheckListBox`, но и допустим `Label`? Хочу сделать кнопку, которая удаляет этот выбранный элемент из моего списка .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bool relay = false;
    int nolIndex = 0;
    int k3 = 0;
    GraphPane pane = zedGraph.GraphPane;
    for (int i = 0; i < Program.axisList[0].sumAxis; i++)
    {
        if (Program.axisList[i].sumPoints == 0)
            nolIndex = i;

    }

    if (nolIndex != 0)
        relay = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        if ((checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick == true)||(checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick == false))&&(номер по которому кликнул)
        {
            if (i < nolIndex)
            {
                k3 = 0;
                checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i+k3);
                pane.CurveList[i + k3].IsVisible = false;
                pane.YAxisList[i + k3].IsVisible = false;
                labelOfAxis[i + k3].Visible = false;
                pane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else if ((i == nolIndex) && (i != 0))
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i + k3);
                pane.CurveList[i + 1].IsVisible = false;
                pane.YAxisList[i + 1].IsVisible = false;
                labelOfAxis[i + 1].Visible = false;
                pane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (relay == true)
                    k3 = 1;
                else
                    k3 = 0;
                checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i + k3);
                pane.CurveList[i + k3].IsVisible = false;
                pane.YAxisList[i + k3].IsVisible = false;
                labelOfAxis[i + k3].Visible = false;
                pane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }

    }
    k3 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У `CheckedListBox` есть свойство `CheckedItems` (можете еще посмотреть свойство `SelectedItems`) - оно возвращает коллекцию отмеченных элементов в данном элементе управления `CheckedListBox`. Читайте [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Чтобы отслеживать изменения выбора элементов, вам нужно обрабатывать событие `ItemCheck` - обработчику передается аргумент `ItemCheckEventArgs`, через который вы можете узнать, какой элемент был отмечен (или флажок был снят). [Подробнее в документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Не получается ни чего, не могу разобраться.

Comment: @Andy в чем у вас проблема?

Comment: Все, разобрался.

Comment: @Andy Если ответ вам помог и вопросов больше нет - примите его.